# Understanding getItem() in FrameStatePagerAdapter

Tags: android, fragmentstatepageradapter, pagerslidingtabstrip

I'm trying to implement sliding tabs in my app following online tutorials. Particularly [this one](http://guides.codepath.com/android/Sliding-Tabs-with-PagerSlidingTabStrip).

What I want to achieve is:

A `MainActivity` with Sliding Tabs based on a single `Fragment`. Each tab showing different data. For this I'm trying to get the current position of the tab selected in my fragment but I don't seem to get the correct value. I'm aware of the function that `getItem()` is called a number of times and sometimes isn't called at all.

So how do I get the current position of the tab selected in fragment? The tutorial I linked passes the position value with the return statement of `getItem()` but that doesn't seem to be working quite well as I'm getting different value in log and `setText`.

```
getItem()

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return PageFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
}
```

PageFragment:

```
public static PageFragment newInstance(int page) {
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(ARG_PAGE, page);
    PageFragment fragment = new PageFragment();
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}
```

Position value difference:

[image: position value fetched in onCreate of fragment]

Answer (score 0):

I've run into a similar issue and I decided to just completely change the "default" `PagerAdapter` so that I wouldn't have to mess around with the `position` myself:

```
/**
 * TabsPagerAdapter.
 *
 * @author Niels
 * @version 1.0
 * @since 11-9-2015
 */
public class TabsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    /**
     * Contains all the fragments.
     */
    private List<Fragment> fragments = new ArrayList<>();

    /**
     * Contains all the tab titles.
     */
    private List<String> tabTitles = new ArrayList<>();

    /**
     * Creates a new PagerAdapter instance.
     *
     * @param fragmentManager The FragmentManager.
     */
    public TabsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
        super(fragmentManager);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return fragments.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return fragments.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return tabTitles.get(position);
    }

    /**
     * Adds the fragment to the list, also adds the fragment's tab title.
     *
     * @param fragment New instance of the Fragment to be associated with this tab.
     * @param tabTitle A String containing the tab title for this Fragment.
     */
    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String tabTitle) {
        fragments.add(fragment);
        tabTitles.add(tabTitle);
    }

}
```

You can use this as such:

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    adapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()); //TabsPagerAdapter = whatever you named the PagerAdapter
    addFragments();
    viewpager.setAdapter(adapter); //viewpager = ViewPager view instance
    strip.setViewPager(viewpager); //strip = PagerSlidingTabStrip view instance
}

/**
 * Adds fragments to the adapter.
 */
private void addFragments() {
    adapter.addFragment(new Fragment1(), "Fragment1");
    adapter.addFragment(new Fragment2(), "Fragment2");
    adapter.addFragment(new Fragment3(), "Fragment3");
    adapter.addFragment(new Fragment4(), "Fragment4");
}
```

Comment: I have a single fragment loading different data based on the tab selected. So I come back to my question, how do I get the position of the selected tab from the fragment as getItem() isn't returning proper values.